# How to get Id from MySQL autoincrement it in C# and Save it

Tags: c#, mysql

I've made a form to save data in C#, what I want to do is get the last Id from my MySQL table, and print it but incremented by 1 in a `TextBox`, then when I save the entire formulary with the other data save the Id printed in the `TextBox`.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is it an auto incrementing field?  If so after your insert use `LAST_INSERT_ID() + 1` to get the ID.  SELECT

Comment: Can you add the code that inserts the data? Are you using an MySqlCommand to execute the insert?

Comment: Why have the number?  The user cannot enter it.  The user should not have to remember it.  Etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can either select the `ID` and add 1 in the SQL

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (Field1) Values (value1); SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() + 1;
```

Or select the id then add it in the c# code

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (Field1) Values (value1); SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html) for more details

```
Select MAX(IdSocio) + 1 FROM Socios
```

Will give you the next ID but this is risky and not recommended.  You cannot be 100% sure of the ID until after it is saved.

Comment: Are you saying you want to populate id with the ID it will be before it is saved?

Comment: what I want to do is this: when I open the form, I want to get the Id incremented by 1, and print it in the textbox, then I can fill the other textboxes, and then save the entire form, in the my SQL table

Comment: What you're asking to do is not best practice and it's why Fred's getting confused. What you should do is not have the application "assume" what the last ID is, and actually "SELECT" the last ID from the database (which is what Fred's code is having you do). What you would do is run the top query in Fred's post. The second part of the query "SELECTS" the last ID. You then would get the return value of the statement and do a textBox1.Text = SQLReturnedID.

Comment: @RyanCarlisle I'm not getting confused, which is why I have said it is not recommended and also said you cannot be sure of an ID until after it has been saved.

Comment: This won't work because you can't get the number until _after_ posting the form.